# How to search multiselect field in NetSuite REST API?

Tags: api, rest, netsuite

I can filter dropdown values and textbox values in NetSuite using REST API, but whenever I search through the multiselect field it returns zero data.
How I can search through a multiselect field in REST API?
Here is my request:

```
https://xxxxxxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryItem?q=multi_select_field_name ANY_OF [4]
```